# How to append column values in dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, databricks

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yD1AY.png)I have a dataframe with two columns (text, useful). I would like to replace any value in "useful" column greater that 20 to 1, else set to zero. Need some help with this. I'm using scala in databricks community

```
+--------------------+------+
|Located in a base...|     0|
| I am not a vegeta  |    12|



+--------------------+------+
|                text|useful|
+--------------------+------+
|Located in a base...|     0|
|I am not a vegeta...|     1|
|There is so many ...|    12|
|Disclaimer: this ...|     0|
|House Special Chi...|     0|
|The food at Chez ...|     2|
|Overall not bad. ...|     3|
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9uzH.png)

[df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9uzH.png)

Comment: Just can't figure this out.                                                                             import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val uDf = Df.withColumn("useful", regexp_replace(col("useful") > 20) => 1)

Comment: I had tried that but keep getting error "error: too many arguments for method withColumn: (colName: String, col: org.apache.spark.sql.Column)org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame"                                 
val uDf = DF.withColumn("label", when(col("label") > 20), 1).otherwise(0)
                                       ^

Comment: I misplaced one bracket so the correct one is `val uDf = Df.withColumn("useful", when((col("useful") > 20), 1).otherwise(0))`

Comment: That's what I was missing. Thanks a lot

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scala: How can I replace value in Dataframes using scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32357774/scala-how-can-i-replace-value-in-dataframes-using-scala)